# Atom package dependency add Unix utils

Tags: atom-editor

I am interested in writing an Atom package that may depend on and call a Unix util, specifically a2ps: https://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes this is possible:

  - in atom you have the node.js platform at your disposal. You can do system calls with `child_process.spawn`.
  - an example on how to do this is in the [graphviz-preview-plus](https://github.com/sverweij/atom-graphviz-preview-plus) package - specifically in [renderGraphVizWithCLI.js](https://github.com/sverweij/atom-graphviz-preview-plus/blob/master/lib/renderGraphVizWithCLI.js) (which is called from [renderGraphViz.js](https://github.com/sverweij/atom-graphviz-preview-plus/blob/master/lib/renderGraphViz.js))